# Plotting half a dataset and not the entire record

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I have dataset with recording period between 1966 to 2019. I want to plot a graph for between 1966 and 1990. What command would I use?

Comment: For subsetting, `x[x$year >= 1966 & x$year <= 1990,]` or `subset(x, year >= 1966 & year <= 1990)` (or `dplyr::filter(x, ...)`, since you included [tag:tidyverse]). For plotting, have you tried `plot`? This question is too vague to be able to provide a reasonable recommendation. The term "plot" could mean just about anything, including histograms, density plots, scatter plots, lines, area plots, bar plots, violin plots, or one of many other things, and it depends on things we do not have: *context* and the *type of data*.

Comment: Lindiwe nkaBANE, your previous questions all have some form of sample data, sample code, or both, I strongly urge you to do the same here (before the question is closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` has a number of ways to restrict axis limits. First, we need some example data:

```
expl <- data.frame(year = rep(1966:2021, 3),
                   value = c(replicate(3, cumsum(rnorm(56, sd = .1)))),
                   id = gl(3,56))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(expl) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = value, color = id)) +
  ggtitle("full plot")
```

One way to restrict the limits of an axis is `coord_cartesian` as in

```
ggplot(expl) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = value, color = id)) +
  ggtitle("restricted x axis") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1966, 1990))
```